# switch implementation; arm; assembler; aarch64; arm64

Tags: performance, assembly, arm, cpu-registers, arm64

I'm interesting in the ways to implement 'switch' operator on aarch64 assembler.
On arm32 platforms I used something like

```
    ldr         pc,         [pc, ta, LSL#2]
    nop                                         // alignment
    .int        .L.case1
    .int        .L.case2
    ...
    .int        .L.caseN
```

But since 64bit version has a lot of restriction on 'pc' register usage, such implementation doesn't work any more.

It seems that the easiest way is to use pair of compare and branch operations, like

```
cmp ta, #1
b.eq .L.case1
cmp ta, #2
b.eq .L.case2
...
```

But sometimes there are up to dozen cases and it would lead to a significant delay before reaching the last 'case'.

Could you share your ideas how to implement fast switch on aarch64, please.

Thanks :)

Comment: adr/adrp can be used for "pc-relative address calculation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an 64-bit ARM assembler to test this with but I believe you would do something like the following to implement a jump table:

```
    adr  x0, jmp_table
    ldr  x0, [x0, x1, LSL#3]
    br   x0

jmp_table:
    .quad .L.case1
    .quad .L.case2
    .quad .L.case3
```

The first instruction, [ADR](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0802b/ADR.html), loads the address of a label into a register. The last instruction, [BR](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0802b/BR.html), jumps to the address stored in the register.

If you're creating a shared library or a position independent executable you can try something like following:

```
    adr  x0, jmp_table
    add  x0, x0, x1, LSL#2
    br   x0

jmp_table:
    b .L.case1
    b .L.case2
    b .L.case3
```

Alternate PIC example

```
    adr  x0, jmp_table
    ldr  w1, [x0, x1, LSL#2]
    add  x0, x0, x1
    br   x0

jmp_table:
    .int  .L.case1 - jmp_table
    .int  .L.case2 - jmp_table
    .int  .L.case3 - jmp_table
```

Comment: when I try to execute this code I got "CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: text relocations (DT_TEXTREL) found in 64-bit ELF file". Compilation & Linking  are work fine... objdump shows this code like: "adr x4, 26ae0; ldr x4, [x4];
br x4; ...; " Yes, just "..." instead of actual addresses. Any ideas why?

Comment: Yes, position independent code is used, it must be on Android 5. Thank you Ross