# In armeabi-v7a, streqh is causing 'invalid instruction, did you mean: strexh, strh?'. Where did the 'eq' go?

Tags: android, assembly, arm

I'm getting this error in some ARM code I'm trying to compile for armeabi-v7a - clearly pre-v7a stuff.

```
jni/6502asm_arm.S:108:2: error: invalid instruction, did you mean: strexh, strh?
streqh r1,[ r4, #28]
```

The last time I programmed ARM assembly was ARM3 on an Archimedes, but it was fairly obvious that `streqh` is a half-word store-if-equal.

I'm completely perplexed by it causing that error message: When did all instructions stop being conditional in ARM? That makes me sad. (I know something about Thumb, but I don't think this is Thumb code.)

I gather that `ex` means 'exclusive' and needs me to get some sort of lock - this application is a BBC emulator for Android, and it's unlikely to be emulating two 6502s at the same time, so  I presume I'm OK with `strh` but what do I do about the `eq`?

Do I need to use the 'if then else' thumb instruction, or jump over it with `bne` or what? I thought the whole 'everything has a condition' idea was central to ARM.

(While I'm writing, I suspect I need to make this code PIC, and there's a table of absolute references to functions implementing 6502 instructions at the end of the source. I presume PC-relative addressing is still complicated by the pipeline length? Is the offset the same for all ARM flavours I'm likely to encounter? Is it still 3 words? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the questions asked in the end: the ARM architecture is largely backwards compatible.  Nothing as fundamental as the number of words `pc` runs ahead of the execution has changed.

Comment: @fuz Brilliant, thanks. I saw some pipelines are huge now, so I was a bit concerned.

Comment: Generally, pipeline length is well-abstracted these days and on modern out-of-order processors, there isn't a pipeline in the traditional sense.  It's a bit much to explain in a comment, but in a nutshell, don't worry about these details.  Instead, read about the new awesome instructions like `ubfx`.

Comment: The value read from PC is now defined as being offset by 8 (two instructions).  How exactly PC can be used in defined manner is largely restricted to cases that it make sense in, so check the documentation for the specific instruction you're using.  In jump tables you can use ADR instruction to let the assembler worry about this. See this answer for a 64-bit ARM relocatable jump table example that should be straightforward to adapt to 32-bit ARM: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32431662

Comment: @fuz ubfx Argh! Haha. Cool. (I need to worry about the 'traditional' three word offset for now; I presume there'll be an armeabi-v8 once those chips find their way into phones and/or they'll be able to operate in some backwards-compatibility mode.)

Comment: @RossRidge Very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Uh,  no, nothing regarding PC has changed between ARMv7 and ARMv8.  You've misunderstood completely. Also smartphones are the main market for ARMv8 processors and has been since the architecture was introduced.

Comment: @RossRidge - Sorry, my reference to the v8 stuff was actually talking to SolidPixel below, who said the PC offset was gone. It's late for me here, and I conflated the posts.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just saw that. SolidPixel appears to misusing the term ARMv8 which refers to a particular ARM architecture and not the new 64-bit ARM instruction set (A64) that it introduced.  ARMv8 CPUs are capable of executing A64 code, 32-bit ARM code (now called A32), and Thumb code.  The ARMv8 architecture doesn't change how reads from the PC register are treated when executing 32-bit ARM code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There has been a [revision in ASM syntax](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM_002dInstruction_002dSet.html#ARM_002dInstruction_002dSet) from *divided syntax*  into *unified syntax* (UAL).  In the new syntax, the execution condition is always last, so the new mnemonic is `strheq`.

These other instructions are just instructions with a name similar to the one you typed.  They have nothing to do with what you want.

Note that if you are programming in thumb mode, you need to have an appropriate `it` instruction in front to set up conditional execution.  Refer to the manual for details.

If you are writing an assembly file for the GNU assembler, you might need to provide a

```
.syntax unified
```

directive to set up unified syntax.  This might be the default for clang's built in assembler, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Perhaps mention `.syntax unified` (I think that's the right directive for GAS) to activate this syntax if it isn't the default.

Comment: Awesomesauce! I have to say, I did think that `streqh` looked a bit weird when I first saw it. I see my compilation now spouts `[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : bbcmicro <= 6502asm_arm.S` so I need to read up about `it` (though I'm surprised the assembler doesn't explode if it hits unsupported conditionals - seems that would make sense).

Comment: @android.weasel Note that you can switch between arm and thumb mode at each jump.  Read up on the “new” `bx`, `brx`, and `blx` instructions.  Also read about “thumb interwork” to avoid some nasty pitfalls.  You generally don't need thumb code for programming on an A-series processor but it doesn't hurt reading up on it.

Answer (score 4):

Your other questions were answered by @fuz

> When did all instructions stop being conditional in ARM?

Only in Aarch64; it's not your problem here.

> I presume PC-relative addressing is still complicated by the pipeline length?

There is the historical fixed offset for pipeline addressing from "back when", but its architected behavior so you can rely on it being the same across implementations. (IIRC, also gone in Aarch64 as it was a slightly random quirk which served no real purpose).

Comment: I wish I could give you a green tick too! Thanks!

Comment: Thumb mode needs `it` to predicate other instructions; part of saving bits was dropping the 4-bit condition from the encoding of every instruction.  Also,IIRC NEON instructions can't be safely predicated.  But yes, like Ross said, you should be saying AArch64; ARMv8 still includes 32-bit ARM/Thumb mode.

Comment: Quite right - sorry, sloppy use of terms on my part. Fixed.