# ARM - Can LDRB be written as LDRBNE?

Tags: assembly, arm

In ARM, we can add conditions to operations like ADD -> ADDNE

Can we do the same for LDRB -> LDRBNE?

Comment: Yes, ARM can predicate load and store instructions, although some assemblers need `ldrneb`, with infix predicate instead of suffix.  As in [In armeabi-v7a, streqh is causing 'invalid instruction, did you mean: strexh, strh?'. Where did the 'eq' go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58896358) .  NEON SIMD instructions aren't guaranteed to work with predication, IIRC, but all traditional integer instructions do.

Comment: which arm instruction set are you asking about?